# Customising SponserPay offer wall

Tags: java, android, ios, iphone, fyber

I have implemented SponsorPay offer wall which shows a list of offers quite easily.But i want to customize the offer wall.i want to get these offers and preview to the user in my own way.Like changing the background color of wall.Without using the orignal SponsorsPay offer wall and making our own.Is there any way to do this? 
Well Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use SponsorPay's OfferwallActivity you can load offers via api and do full customization yourself.

http://developer.sponsorpay.com/content/android/offer-wall/offer-api/

You need to contact publishers@sponsorpay.com for activating api as its not activated by default.